# Android mediaProjection + SurfaceView + overlay views

Tags: android, video, view, overlay, android-mediaprojection

I would like to ask, if it's possible to improve FPS for recording screen with overlay views.

Pseudo structure of app:

1) Fullscreen FrameLayout in AppCompatActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

            <RelativeLayout
                ...
            >

                <ImageView
                    ...
                />

                <TextView
                    ...
                />

            </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

2) Camera Preview with SurfaceView:

```
class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

3) Get SurfaceView (CameraPreview), add CameraPreview to FrameLayout, bring to front

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera); //surfaceView
frameLayout.addView(mPreview); //add surfaceView to root: FrameLayout
controls.bringToFront(); //bring controls to top Z-order
```

4) Create input surface + create virtual display and render the virtual display to surface via `MediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(...)` Next using `MediaMuxer` for Audio/Video mux streams.

**Point 3: the problem**
When i comment line: `controls.bringToFront();` video has ~30FPS, but without overlay views in video.
When i uncomment line: `controls.bringToFront();` video has overlay views in video, but FPS is only ~20.

OR

When i disable `CameraPreview` video has ~30FPS, but without camera preview.

Problem can be probably with overlay views. When i enable overdraw in debug mode on device: [see](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-overdraw.html)
camera preview is overdraw 1x (purple)
ImageView is overdraw 2x (green)
TextView is overdraw 3x (pink)

When i enable profiling GPU Rendering in debug mode on device: [see](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-rendering.html)
I have all bars under green line (16ms).

Maybe i have something inefficient. The Goal is record screen with the same FPS with/without overlay views. It is possible?

**Tests with `screenrecord` command and Hardware Composer:**

**A)** enabled views overlay; enabled camera preview:
`$ ./adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 --bit-rate 6000000 /storage/sdcard1/demo3.mp4` and result is video file: 1280 x 720;H.264 / AVC;**20FPS**;bit-rate:4585 kb/s.

Hardware Composer:

```
type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name 
HWC | 557cf928d0 | 0000 | 0000 | 04 | 0100 | ? 00000011  |    0.0,    0.0, 1280.0,  720.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | SurfaceView
HWC | 557cf40dd0 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | com.example.test/com.example.test.RecordActivity
FB TARGET | 557cf3fd00 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
```

**B)** disable overlay (`//controls.bringToFront();`), so only camera preview enabled:
`$ ./adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 --bit-rate 6000000 /storage/sdcard1/demo4.mp4` and result is video file: 1280 x 720;H.264 / AVC;**30FPS**;bit-rate:6684 kb/s.

Hardware Composer:

```
type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name 
HWC | 557cf46610 | 0000 | 0000 | 04 | 0100 | ? 00000011  |    0.0,    0.0, 1280.0,  720.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | SurfaceView
FB TARGET | 557cf3fd00 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
```

**C)** only `android:id="@+id/frameLayout"`+`android:id="@+id/controls"` layouts enabled; enabled camera preview:
`$ ./adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 --bit-rate 6000000 /storage/sdcard1/demo5.mp4` and result is video file: 1280 x 720;H.264 / AVC;**30FPS**;bit-rate:4280 kbps.

Hardware Composer:

```
type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name 
HWC | 557cf6e910 | 0000 | 0000 | 04 | 0100 | ? 00000011  |    0.0,    0.0, 1280.0,  720.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | SurfaceView
FB TARGET | 557cf04f30 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
```

**D)** only `android:id="@+id/frameLayout"`+`android:id="@+id/controls"` + `<ImageView ...` layouts enabled; enabled camera preview:
`$ ./adb shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 --bit-rate 6000000 /storage/sdcard1/demo3.mp4` and result is video file: 1280 x 720;H.264 / AVC;**20FPS**;bit-rate:2879 kbps.

Hardware Composer:

```
type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name 
HWC | 557cfa2040 | 0000 | 0000 | 04 | 0100 | ? 00000011  |    0.0,    0.0, 1280.0,  720.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | SurfaceView
HWC | 557cfb6be0 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |  590.0,  880.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |  590,  880,  720, 1280 | com.example.test/com.example.test.RecordActivity
FB TARGET | 557cf04f30 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |    0.0,    0.0,  720.0, 1280.0 |    0,    0,  720, 1280 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
```

**Tests with `systrace`:**
(Images are combine from 1.5 images to height for more information.)

**E)** enabled overlay, camera preview, run recording:
[image]

**F)** disable overlay (`//controls.bringToFront();`), camera preview, run recording:
[image]

**G)** enabled overlay, **disable Alpha on all views**, camera preview, run recording: 
[image]

Alerts are about:

- Inefficient View alpha usage: `Setting an alpha between 0 and 1 has significant performance costs, if one of the fast alpha paths is not used.` => For case G: i disabled alpha on all views. Alerts was removed, but FPS is still:20.
- Scheduling delay: `Work to produce this frame was descheduled for several milliseconds, contributing to jank. Ensure that code on the UI thread doesn't block on work being done on other threads, and that background threads (doing e.g. network or bitmap loading) are running at android.os.Process#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND or lower so they are less likely to interrupt the UI thread. These background threads should show up with a priority number of 130 or higher in the scheduling section under the Kernel process.` => still not solved.

But it is interesting, because, when i comment: `//controls.bringToFront();` (case F), so `controls` layout is behind camera preview (if i understand), so alpha on bitmaps processing is still execute, but FPS is: 30 => good.

Differences, that i saw from compare case E/F/G (scale is ~5 seconds):

- case F/G: something work on CPUs: 4,5,6,7, case E not.
- in `surfaceFlinger` is name of App: com.*.pso (it is my RecordActivity):
  case E: 184 items,
  case F: 312 items,
  case G: 204 items.
  Count of items is similar for `SurfaceView` graph.
- in `/system/bin/surfaceflinger`: command `onDraw()`
  Case E: slices: ~7000 has wall duration: ~3300ms,
  case F: slices: ~11000 has wall duration: ~2300ms,
  case G: slices: ~7800 has wall duration: ~3400ms.
- in `/system/bin/surfaceflinger` from `Binder_1` to `Binder_5`: command `dequeueBuffer`
  Case E: slices: ~1200 has wall duration ~3500ms,
  case F: slices: ~2080 has wall duration ~38ms,
  case G: slices: ~1509 has wall duration ~3200ms,
- in `/system/bin/mediaserver` in `IppExecuterThre` is similar situation as in `surfaceflinger`. `dequeueBuffer`
  Case E: slices: 282 has wall duration ~3600ms,
  case F: slices: 462 has wall duration ~117ms,
  case G: slices: 304 has wall duration ~3300ms.

So remove alpha from overlay view lightly improve performance, but not increase FPS.

Comment: If you use an external recorder, like the `screenrecord` command, do you get the same results? In the configuration where the app is recording at 20fps, can you tell if it also runs at 20fps when you're *not* recording? (Just want to separate frame generation from recording behavior... if it's running at 20fps with or without recording enabled, then you can remove MediaProjection from the set of things to worry about.)

Comment: Post updated. (Not tried with recording enabled, because FPS was very slow, with recording via MediaProjection+MediaMuxer and `screenrecord` command. Tried with run activity with enabled/disabled overlay and enabled camera preview, but without recording.)

Comment: It's certainly possible you're hitting a performance wall on your particular device. Recording the screen adds the GPU layer composition for the virtual display, plus the video encoding itself. On some devices, running `screenrecord` make a noticeable difference on basic apps, while on others you won't even know it's running. A careful analysis of systrace traces is the only way to really see what's going on under the hood. You might want to check the HWC configuration to see what all is being composed; I added a note to my answer about where and how to look.

Answer (score 1):

There are two independent things going on:

1. The rendering and composition of the Views.  This happens on a single layer, and is performed by the application itself.
2. The rendering and composition of the layers.  This happens within SurfaceFlinger, the system graphics compositor.

Normally #2 can be done with hardware overlays -- each layer is passed to the display hardware, which does the composition as the pixels are sent to the display.  For a virtual display, there's no display hardware involved, and the composition is performed on the GPU, by SurfaceFlinger.

It's hard to say what is causing the effects you're seeing.  Could be that the application is slowing down and updating less often, could be that the virtual display overhead is taxing the GPU to the point where it can no longer keep up.   If you've only got two layers (View and SurfaceView), the layer composition overhead shouldn't be that bad.

The only way to know for sure is to use [systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html) to capture a trace of the system in "fast" and "slow" modes and figure out why they differ.

**Add:** A quick look at the layer stack in Hardware Composer might be interesting, just to see how things look in the different configurations.  If you `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` you'll get a big pile of output; near the bottom will be something that looks [like this](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#composition).  That'll tell you what the layers are, how big they are, and how they're ordered.